# What in exifr causes this Tempfile to get closed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

In this piece of Ruby code that processes an `UploadedFile` using [exifr](https://github.com/remvee/exifr)

```rb
f = uploaded_file.tempfile
p "1 #{f.closed?} #{f.instance_variable_get(:'@unlinked')}"
#1 EXIFR::JPEG.new(StringIO.new(f.read))
#2 EXIFR::JPEG.new(f)
p "2 #{f.closed?} #{f.instance_variable_get(:'@unlinked')}"
GC.start
sleep 0.01
p "3 #{f.closed?} #{f.instance_variable_get(:'@unlinked')}"
p "4 #{f.size}"
```

N.B. GC.start/sleep is there to make the problem replicate reliably.

when uncommenting `#1`, all is fine:

```
"1 false false"
"2 false false"
"3 false false"
"4 3822528"
```

However, the outcome of uncommenting `#2`, instead of `#1`, yields this:

```
"1 false false"
"2 false false"
"3 true false"
[c4b7ce6b-5492-43db-8c64-726cafaccce0] [Thread: 24800] Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_size - /var/folders/vx/v0rn818s0257_3l491_v48bm0000gn/T/RackMultipart20240221-71765-acbi7v.JPG):
```

Now all that exifr is doing is this:

```rb
    def initialize(file, load_thumbnails: true)
...
        examine(file.dup, load_thumbnails: load_thumbnails)
...
      end
    end

    class Reader < SimpleDelegator
      def readbyte; readchar; end unless File.method_defined?(:readbyte)
      def readint; (readbyte << 8) + readbyte; end
      def readframe; read(readint - 2); end
      def readsof; [readint, readbyte, readint, readint, readbyte]; end
      def next
        c = readbyte while c != 0xFF
        c = readbyte while c == 0xFF
        c
      end
    end

    def examine(io, load_thumbnails: true)
      io = Reader.new(io)
...
```

and a bit of reading from `io`, so I don't understand what would cause the file to get closed.

This happens in a Rails app running on puma.

#2 would be preferable, as it does not require the file to be loaded into memory completely (in my case, we are talking up to 50 MB).

Comment: What object is `uploaded_file.tempfile`? What class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Casper, I understood I got duped by f.dup - wouldn't have thought that part of the standard Ruby library would behave this way - deleting a Tempfile when a (dup'ed) reference is still around.

The way I chose to fix this is different from Casper's solutions, though, because I already have an open Tempfile, and I want to use it, instead of concurrently re-opening the file. (Who knows what implications that would have, on different OSes?)

So this is how I fixed it:

```rb
EXIFR::JPEG.new(SelfDuper.new(f))
```

And this is the helper class I wrote for it:

```rb
require 'delegate'

class SelfDuper < SimpleDelegator
  def dup
    self
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why this happens is most likely because of this explanation in the `Tempfile` documentation:

> **When a Tempfile object is garbage collected**, or when the Ruby interpreter
> exits, **its associated temporary file is automatically deleted**.

Now `EXIFR` does `file.dup` on the file object when it calls `examine`. This duplicated object will be garbage collected once `EXIFR` is done reading the file, and as a side effect of this garbage collection, the temporary file will be deleted.

Let's call this problem a `Tempfile` race condition. `Tempfile` is most likely not "dup-safe", and `EXIFR` is probably programmed expecting a `File` object, in which case this problem would not happen.

Therefore the solution is to not use `EXIFR::JPEG.new(f)`, if you want to retain the temporary file for later processing.

The other solution is to open the temporary file yourself using a `File` object, and pass that object to `EXIFR::JPEG.new` instead.

This way you will not have to read the file into memory, nor will garbage collection delete the temporary file as long as you maintain a reference to `f` somewhere.

And the final and probably easiest solution is to notice that `EXIFR` also accepts a file path string to the `initialize` method. Therefore this will probably be the simplest fix:

```
EXIFR::JPEG.new(f.path)
```